# SQL - Paired Movie Genres

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which maps genres to movies.

```
GENRE       | MOVIE
--------------------------
Drama       | Boring Movie
Action      | Boring Movie
Comedy      | Boring Movie
Documentary | Epic Movie
Romantic    | Epic Movie
Action      | Epic Movie
Drama       | Epic Movie
Action      | Lost
Drama       | Lost    
---------------------------
```

I want to write an MySQL statement which tells me what two genres are most often linked to the same movie? Here the answer would be Action/Drama because they are paired in all 3 movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a self join to handle the "linked to the same movie" requirement, but not to the same exact record.

```
SELECT movie_genre.genre, peer.genre as peer_genre, COUNT(*)
FROM movie_genre
JOIN movie_genre AS peer
  ON movie_genre.MOVIE = peer.MOVIE
  AND movie_genre.GENRE < peer.GENRE
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC ,1
LIMIT 1
```

More readable solution

```
SELECT movie_genre.genre AS Genre1, peer.genre as Genre2, COUNT(*) As Relations
FROM movie_genre
JOIN movie_genre AS peer
  ON movie_genre.MOVIE = peer.MOVIE
    AND movie_genre.GENRE < peer.GENRE
GROUP BY Genre1, Genre2
ORDER BY Relations desc ,Genre1
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You can avoid the issue of having each result appearing twice by using a `<` instead of `<>`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you are correct - much better solution (less joins).  {changed above}

Comment: Thank you so much. Words can't describe how helpful that was.

Comment: I've never seen GROUP BY/ORDER BY with indices instead of column names before. Is that possible in mysql? (Remark: Even if it is, I would find that pretty error-prone.)

Comment: @cyroxx - Its possible. I don't necessarily agree that it is error prone as much as less readable and harder to maintain. --> I added more readable solution above

Answer (score 2):

```
select genre, count(distinct movie) as movie_count
from your_table
group by genre
order by movie_count desc
limit 2
```